# apply function to subsets of each row in R

Tags: r, apply

I am struggling to find a way to apply a specific function using apply, only to a "chunk" of a specific row.
For instance, I have a matrix:

```
x <- matrix(c(5,12,4,3,2,8,10,7,9,1,11,6),nrow=3)


    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5    3   10    1
[2,]   12    2    7   11
[3,]    4    8    9    6
```

And I would like to end up with a new matrix, made up of a sum of the first and last two values in each row. Like so:

```
       [,1] [,2] 
[1,]    8    11   
[2,]   14    18    
[3,]   12    15
```

I have tried something like this:

```
chunks<-c("1:2","3:4")

 sumchunks<-function(x,chunks){
  apply(x,1,
        function(row){
          for (i in chunks){
            v<-sum(row[chunks[i]])
          }})

}
```

But it doesn't work at all. Any suggestion on successful ways?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to `array` and then do

```
t(apply(array(x, c(3, 2, 2)), 1, colSums))
```

Or

```
sapply(seq(1, ncol(x), 2), function(i) rowSums(x[,i:(i+1)]))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    8   11
#[2,]   14   18
#[3,]   12   15
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
chunks <- list(1:2, 3:4)
sumchunks <- function(x, chunks) sapply(chunks, function(ch) sum(x[ch]))

x <- matrix(c(5,12,4,3,2,8,10,7,9,1,11,6),nrow=3)
apply(x, 1, sumchunks, chunks=chunks)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    8   14   12
# [2,]   11   18   15
```

Eventually you want to transpose the result.
Here is a vectorized variant:

```
chunks <- list(1:2, 3:4)
x <- matrix(c(5,12,4,3,2,8,10,7,9,1,11,6),nrow=3)
sapply(chunks, function(ch) rowSums(x[,ch]))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    8   11
# [2,]   14   18
# [3,]   12   15
```

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
x <- matrix(sample(1:12),nrow=3)
f = function(s) {
    c(sum(s[1:2]), sum(s[3:4]))
}
t(apply(x, 1, f))
```

Comment: @JoshuaDrake I suppose this is an answer to the question with a detailed R code, but not a request for clarification. Actually OP makes question pretty clear, there is no need for additional clarification.

Answer (score 1):

`rowSums` was built to sum over rows so should be quite fast. You can limit the columns you want to sum over and then `cbind` them to get what you want:

```
cbind(rowSums(x[,c(1,2)]), rowSums(x[,c(3,4)]))

#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    8   11
#[2,]   14   18
#[3,]   12   15
```